# How to design squeak and creak sounds of metal objects?

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, physics

Are there valid guidelines to design squeak and creak sounds produced by metal objects?

Here are some examples:
[Example 1](https://www.audioblocks.com/stock-audio/metal-squeak-1-sound-effect.html)
[Example 2](https://www.audioblocks.com/stock-audio/metal-squeak-2-sound-effect.html)
[Example 3](https://www.audioblocks.com/stock-audio/metal-squeak-3-sound-effect.html)

Answer (score 3):

A violin bow on a cymbal can make some cool squeaky/creaky sounds.

Using a piezo disc taped to the cymbal as a transducer can help make it more metallic sounding than using a microphone, but either way is fun.

If you don't care about scratching the cymbal you can also experiment with scraping metal objects against it. Hardened metal (like a good screwdriver tip) can be nice and creaky.

I'm sure there are other ways, too..

Answer (score 1):

Sound Design is a creative pursuit. Consequently the way to progress in Sound Design is to learn the common techniques involved, such as:

- Sound Recording
- Editing
- Layering
- Pitch and Tone manipulation
- Audio Processing
- Mixing
- etc.

Once you are familiar with these techniques, begin to experiment with particular sounds and see what you come up with.

There are no other guidelines than this.

Answer (score -2):

Talk to your local torsion testing laboratory record real metal